# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app1'

Tags: django, module, modulenotfounderror, django-apps, vs-community-edition

Created a new app named 'app1'.
Have included the app name under INSTALLED_APPS settings.
Got the error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app1''

Request your help.

Comment: no need to post a question for this my friend. 
Please just follow the official django tutorial and if you follow every step closely,it should be working.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: The `app1` folder is in the `Project0` folder - think you need to include the full path in your settings `Project0.app1`

Comment: Thank you dear Pfinnn. I am aware that I missed the point of creating the app into the main node and instead created it inside the Project0 folder. I am just trying to understand, what makes the error appear. Why shouldn't the app be created within the Project0 folder.

Comment: Lain, could you please eloborate? I tried to give exactly as you mentioned, but got a new error. like below,
jango.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'app1'. Check that 'Project0.app1.apps.Ap1Config.name' is correct.
I also checked apps.py and its like below,

class app1Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'app1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Lain!
Modified the apps.py to

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class app1Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'Project0.app1'
```

and the settings.py as

```
Project0.app1.apps.app1Config
```

runserver worked!